# Extended ASP.NET user not saving into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to make a music website /with educational purposes/. I wanted to use ASP.NET Identity User, but also I wanted to add some extra properties. I am doing code first. So I made a Model layer where I am extending the Identity User like this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    //Some extra data that I want to add goes here

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

So far so good. Next I implemented my Data layer with Repository and Unit Of Work patterns and on the top of them is my Services layer /MVC project/. I ran it and I registered an User and I was redirected as that user. I though everything is okay so I decided to check my database. I saw the tables, provided by ASP.NET, but they were empty. I tried to register the same user and I was noticed that there is an user with this email, already.

I checked the connection strings and everything was fine. I am running out of ideas...

[image]

I am totally mistaken somewhere, but I can find it. I will attach my project if someone wants to see the code.

[**Source code**](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZIRDHZOHWpdBVdJXHNJu48D8zwPBJsRfQX)

Comment: Probably the usual localDb confusion. It's not stored where you think it is.

Comment: Hve you tried Json Action Result for Async Task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found what was wrong in the whole picture. In the models there is an ApplicationDbContext.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DatabaseConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

There by default the connection is set on DefaultConnection so it does not work how I wanted to.

Comment: My situation is same. I changed the DefaultConnection to DatabaseConnection in both places but got not success.
I am calling the api from postman.

Answer (score 0):

So what happens is that yes, it is being inserted into the database. However, the data table is not being refreshed. What I use to solve the issue is something like this:

```
   private void showData()
    {
        string conString = @"your;connection;string;"

        SqlDataAdapter sda;
        DataTable dt;


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM yourTableName", con);


        dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Then just run showData() on load or on click of a refresh button.

I had the same issue when designing my own application. Hope this helps.

Comment: My table is refreshed I am 100% sure. Even I tried your suggestion, but this does not changed anything at all. Thanks anyway

Comment: Glad you found a solution!